# 'drush' is appended to each path breaking its commands

Tags: drush

I don't normally use Drush on Windows, but tried it and noticed that it appends *drush* as a kind of root directory for any action, thus breaking said action.

For example, `drush dd` gives:

> The command could not be executed successfully (returned: 'Path/To/Composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. , code: 1)

The correct path is *Path/To/Composer/vendor/drush/drush*.

When running `drush en mymodule`, the debug information contains the following.

> [preflight] Alias paths: drupal\site\root/drush/sites,drupal/site/root/drush/sites

*drupal/site/root/sites* I think makes more sense.

The error is *Command pm:enable was not found*.

Maybe this is a coincidence and the two are unrelated, but how does one configure Drush directories?

The Drush version is 9.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Drush under Windows, but something tells me that the problem could be solved by by editing the path to the Drush executable, perhaps in a Windows environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have installed Drush 9 correctly as Drush is trying to execute

```
Path/To/Composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush
```

Drush 9 should be installed site-locally, not globally, and be launched using Drush Launcher - see http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

We can't help you anymore without knowing how you installed Drupal and Drush. The recommended approach to install Drupal is using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project (which includes a site-local Drush).

PS! `vendor/drush/drush/drush` exists, but it is a script for Linux.